# Matlab: Function that returns a string with the first n characters of the alphabet

Tags: matlab

I'd like to have a function `generate(n)` that generates the first `n` lowercase characters of the alphabet appended in a string (therefore: `1<=n<=26`)

For example:

```
generate(3) --> 'abc'
generate(5) --> 'abcde'
generate(9) --> 'abcdefghi'
```

I'm new to Matlab and I'd be happy if someone could show me an approach of how to write the function. For sure this will involve doing arithmetic with the ASCII-codes of the characters - but I've no idea how to do this and which types that Matlab provides to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rely on [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for this. You can convert an integer to a character using [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html).

So for example if we want an "e", we could look up the ASCII code for "e" (101) and write:

```
char(101)

    'e'
```

This also works for arrays:

```
char([101, 102])

     'ef'
```

The nice thing in your case is that in ASCII, the lowercase letters are all the numbers between 97 ("a") and 122 ("z"). Thus the following code works by taking ASCII "a" (97) and creating an array of length `n` starting at 97. These numbers are then converted using `char` to strings. As an added bonus, the version below ensures that the array can *only* go to 122 (ASCII for "z").

```
function output = generate(n)
    output = char(97:min(96 + n, 122));
end
```

> Note: For the upper limit we use `96 + n` because if `n` were 1, then we want `97:97` rather than `97:98` as the second would return "ab". This could be written as `97:(97 + n - 1)` but the way I've written it, I've simply pulled the "-1" into the constant.

You could also make this a simple anonymous function.

```
generate = @(n)char(97:min(96 + n, 122));
generate(3)

    'abc'
```

To write the most portable and robust code, I would probably not want those hard-coded ASCII codes, so I would use something like the following:

```
output = 'a':char(min('a' + n - 1, 'z'));
```

Comment: +1 well explained. Just to avoid any magic numbers in the code I would use `generate = @(n)'a':char(min('a'+n-1,'z'))`

Comment: @Daniel good point, I *almost* wrote just that. I'll update as I agree it is better.

Answer (score 0):

...or, you can just generate the entire alphabet and take the part you want:

```
function str = generate(n)
   alphabet = 'a':'z';
   str = alphabet(1:n);
end
```

Note that this will fail with an index out of bounds error for `n > 26`, so you might want to check for that.

Comment: @Crowley Yes it would.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `char` built-in function which converts an interger value (or array) into a character array.

**EDIT**
Bug fixed (ref. Suever's comment)

```
function [str]=generate(n)
a=97;
% str=char(a:a+n)
str=char(a:a+n-1)
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: This code doesn't work as if I pass `n = 1`, I get "ab" rather than "a"